# Can GlusterFS notifies after synchronizations?

Tags: synchronization, filesystems, synchronized, glusterfs

I have several questions about the way GlusterFS synchronizes files.

- Is there a way I can get notified when a synchronization has finished on a client or a server ? For instance, are synchronizations logged somewhere ?
- Let's say I want to synchronize a whole directory, will it be synchronized file by file or once for all ? This can actually be an important information if I want to use things like inotify on synchronized directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GlusterFS is not a file sync utility, it is a virtual filesystem.  It works by aggregating local storage on several servers then making the unified storage available to clients via FUSE mounts or directly through a client API.

When you write files into a replicated GlusterFS volume the files are written to all replicas at the same time, there is no sync delay.

Comment: Let's imagine you want to write a very large file on your filesystem. Your bandwidth will provoke some delay. Do you mean the file is considered as written only after it is transmitted to the server ?

Comment: "Considered" seems out of place.  The file really *is* written by transferring it to the server(s).  You should try glusterfs and see for yourself how it works.  Lets continue this on IRC where it will be easier to answer your specific questions.