# Can GlusterFS clients synchronize subdirectories

Tags: synchronization, filesystems, synchronized, glusterfs

This question might be naive but I could not quickly find an answer in the documentation, so it may be the right place to ask.

Can GlusterFS clients only synchronize a subdirectory? For example, Dropbox allows you to only synchronize a subdirectory of someone's repository.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GlusterFS is not a file sync utility, it is a virtual filesystem.  See my complete answer to your related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22459874/3429709

Answer (score 0):

semiosis is correct.

GlusterFS has a feature called "geo-replication" that performs asynchronous replication. As of now, this is done at volume level and cannot be achieved on a per directory basis. You can read more about it here - http://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/1037-synchronise-a-glusterfs-volume-to-a-remote-site-using-geo-replication